# How to arrange the features extracted from a CNN in a grid to pass in an RNN Encoder in Keras or tf 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to produce the code used in paper [What You Get Is What You See:
A Visual Markup Decompiler](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04938v1.pdf) which is basically implemented in `Lua` by Harvard NLP by the name of [im2latex](https://github.com/harvardnlp/im2markup/). The problem is that all of the codes available in either in Torch or tensorflow 1. I want to implement he same code in `Keras` or tensorflow 2.0.

There is a part in the paper where it is written as:

**The model first extracts image features using a convolutional neural network (CNN) and arranges the features in a grid. Each row is then encoded using a recurrent neural network (RNN)**

[image]

So it is basically a three part process for the encodr part.
Here is what I have done is that I have VGG19 model for transfer learning like. In my model, I'll be using the output of the VGG19 model to get the features as

Part-1 : Extract the Features from the VGG-19

```
extracted_feat = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False,weights="imagenet",
input_shape=(224,224,3),pooling='avg',)
```

Part-2: Change the extracted features in the Grid

```
grid_output = change_to_grid(extracted_feat)
```

what and how Should the method `change_to_grid` be doing here?? How am I supposed to make a grid out of the tensors? By transposing or what?

Part-3 : Pass Extracted Features to an LSTM or RNN to act as encoder

```
encoder_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(254,return_sequence=True,return_state=true)(grid_output)
```

**Please suggest what should be the code for the second part**. Also please suggest if I am doing something wrong here.